# How can I reset my variable?

Tags: java, android, xml, resources, manifest

**How can I set a variable in one class, and then change it in another, and then use the changed variable in a third class?**

I have a variable currentTime that is of the Application class, meaning it can be used in all activities:

[image]

I made a game, and whenever the person loses, it displays the time they played the app:

[image]

This works fine, but then I have another button on the gameOver activity. It takes the user back to the Main_Menu to start the game again. The thing is, I want the variable currentTime to reset whenever the onCreate method of the Main_Menu. Otherwise, the time just keeps on adding onto itself.

For example, if I play the game for 5 seconds and then lose, **my score is five.** Then I click "Play Again!" and play for 6 seconds, my score **should be six.** Instead it displays **eleven**. How do I stop my app from adding up the times, when I want it to reset? I need to somehow call activityCount.java again, but that is only called at the start of the app. How do I address this issue? Thanks so much, I really appreciate your help!

BTW: If you need any more code or anything that you think could help you help me solve this issue, feel free to let me know, and I will try and post it here!

**Here is something that I think could work, its just that I have know idea as to how...**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I shouldn't have used the Application class, since it runs everytime the app starts, even before the onCreate method. This made it hard for me to go back to that class and reset the variables. Here is my solution:

[image]

Now it's simple. Instead of making it confusing and adding multiple methods to do different tasks, just keep one. Call that one method every time the button to play the game is pressed.

**You will notice that it doesn't extend application class anymore** That is for the same reason.

[image]

That's it! just call one static method, which sets the time of the static variable. Then, you can address that variable later. No reset methods needed!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to add a constructor to the activity account class that calls the application class's constructor, aswell as instantiates the "currentTime" to be System.currentTimeMillis();

This, or i would reset the variable to zero when you request to play the game again, resetting the score. ( maybe make the time -= System.currentTimeMillis();)

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

You could try this, for the second method, by creating a resetTime method

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public void resetTime(){
    this.currentTime -= System.currentTimeMills();
}
```

Or, for the first method i recommended, something like this

```
public activityCount(){
    super();
    this.currentTime -= System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

and then re-initialise the object each time you die,

It's kind of hard to explain without seeing every class, but you basically want to reset the time each time you die, to what it was when the program first started. This could also be done by storing this initial time ( Time when the program started ) in a seperate variable with-in your main class or other class methods. Then you can set currentTime to this when you should need it. Hopefully one of these plans fix's your error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by add a constructor that calls the application class's constructor. Could you please provide an example? I have tried the second way, except that just changes an instance of the currentTime, and not the original currentTime, which won't let us change or call it from any other activity. Please help. Thank you so much for your help and time, I really appreciate it. I will make sure to mark you best answer and like your answer once I see an example, or understand a way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Okay, I am still really confused. In the first method, what do you mean re-initialise the object each time you die? Also, isn't doing **this.currentTime -=System.currentTimeMillis();** going to have currentTime always have a value of 0? It's like I somehow want to first call a method that gets the currentTime, and then call a method that resets the current time. That would be ideal. For the second method, where and when do I call the resetTime() method? Thanks, I really appreciate all of your help. I will mark you as my best answer once these confusions are cleared. Thanks

Comment: By the way, I put in a picture at the very end of my answer to further clarify my question; I think it is similar to what you are telling me. Have a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you put this currentTime in the Application class, it doesn't make much sense to me.

I think you should just declare it as a static member of a class, or put it in a singleton class, and then update the value every time you start the game, instead of launching the app.